# Can't get rewrite rule to work

Tags: php, apache

I followed instruction from this website which are great:

http://www.datakoncepts.com/seo

mod_rewrite is working because first I use:

```
print_r(in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()));
```

and this return one, but when I do the test mentioned on the page (create test.html and test.php and get a rule to swap test.html to test.php), it's working.

So now I have a webpage such as: www.toto.com/TEST/category.php?cat=1

and the rule is (to please Mike I added the RewriteEngine On):

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/$ category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

And this doesn't work? Could someone please help?

PS: .htaccess lives in www.toto.com/TEST/

I am testing this on localhost using XAMPP.

## EDIT:

The problem is that I thought this would actually modify the way the URL looks like. So it does actually seem to make the substitution. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Would actually swap the content of category.php?cat=1 to ^index.php, but what I wanted was for the URL to be re-written. In other words to have:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Showing up as:

www.toto.com/TEST/category/1/

in the URL (assuming the original URL was www.toto.com/TEST/category.php?cat=1).

And in my particular case that doesn't seem to the case? Why? How do we do that then?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? For example, what is your goal?

Comment: I hope this helps: http://www.emrerothzerg.com/blog/how-to-make-sef-url-for-php-websites-function-htaccess/

Comment: If that is your entire `.htaccess`, you forgot to add the ["turn the rewrite engine on"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) command, without which no rewrite rules will be processed.

Comment: @jerdiggity My goal is to rewrite category.php?cat=$1 into anything else really and I can't even do this at the moment. Ideally it should be www.toto.com/TEST/category/1/ if for instance cat=1. thank you.

Comment: @Mike thanks but as I said, Rewrite rule is working when it comes to switch an html for its php equivalent, it's just the second rule that doesn't work!

Comment: then show your full `.htaccess` file please. Don't just post the lines you think don't work, show the whole attempt =)

Comment: @Mike I agree but the post is quite explicit about the fact the I was able to get a substitution working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go;

If your .htaccess file in your root folder

```
RewriteEngine On   
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^TEST/category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /TEST/category.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
```

If your .htaccess file in your TEST folder

```
RewriteEngine On   
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
```

TEST URL:
http://emrerothzerg.com/stackoverflow/index/212

http://emrerothzerg.com/stackoverflow/index.php?cat=212

CODES:

```
RewriteEngine On   
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
```

P.s. the .htaccess file in /stackoverflow/ folder

Comment: It's cool and I am sure this is the right answer, just tried and it doesn't work. So it has to be something else somewhere, and mod_rewrite works... that's the worse.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's great, but again I still can't get it to work. Which is odd because it's a very basic case.

Comment: the problem could your .htaccess file (if it contains some other codes) or your local server. I recommend WAMP server for local

Comment: There's nothing else in the file but these 3 lines. I use XAMPP. And as I said the html php swap test worked?!

Comment: sorry but in fact looking at your example. If you click in the second link, shouldn't it rewrite the URL as http://emrerothzerg.com/stackoverflow/index/212 because when you click on this link you get 212 displayed in the browser but the URL stays the same?

Comment: it does work, I will make an edit. I think I got confused. I thought this would be responsible for changing the "URL" but it doesn't. It actually swap the content of the files in the browser but doesn't change the address in the address bar?

Comment: I think you're talking about redirecting URLS from /category.php?cat=1 to /category/1 , you can redirect url from non-sef url to sef url by PHP, if you can't do it, I can help you with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59307/discussion-between-user18490-and-emre).